# Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.28.0.2:2181 on Docker for ZooKeeper

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm trying to use apache kafka with docker. But when I run this, I get the following error on kafka container.

```
Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.28.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.28.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```

using
Docker Engine 20.10.6
Docker Client 20.10.6
on Apple Macbook Air M1.

```yaml
version: '2.1'

services:
  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper:3.4.9
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_PORT: 2181
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
    volumes:
      - ./data/vol/zoo1/data:/data
      - ./data/vol/zoo1/datalog:/datalog

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.1
    hostname: kafka1
    ports:
      - "3344:3344"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:3344
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9999
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: ${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}
    volumes:
      - ./data/kafka1:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
```

This is the complete log, until kafka quits. It says zookeeper is healthy and with docker ps I get zookeeper is indeed running and open to the ports according to the config.

```
docker compose up --build
[+] Running 3/2
 ⠿ Network logflow_default     Created                                                                                                                                                                                                   3.8s
 ⠿ Container logflow_zoo1_1    Created                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 ⠿ Container logflow_kafka1_1  Created                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
Attaching to kafka1_1, zoo1_1
kzoo1_1    | ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
zoo1_1    | Using config: /conf/zoo.cfg
^R
kafka1_1  | ===> User
kafka1_1  | uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
kafka1_1  | ===> Configuring ...
kafka1_1  | ===> Running preflight checks ... 
kafka1_1  | ===> Check if /var/lib/kafka/data is writable ...
kafka1_1  | ===> Check if Zookeeper is healthy ...
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.5.8-f439ca583e70862c3068a1f2a7d4d068eec33315, built on 05/04/2020 15:53 GMT
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:host.name=kafka1
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_212
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.vendor=Azul Systems, Inc.
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu-8-amd64/jre
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.class.path=/etc/confluent/docker/docker-utils.jar
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.name=Linux
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.version=5.10.25-linuxkit
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.name=root
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.home=/root
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.dir=/
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.memory.free=28MB
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.memory.max=443MB
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.memory.total=31MB
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=zoo1:2181 sessionTimeout=40000 watcher=io.confluent.admin.utils.ZookeeperConnectionWatcher@cc34f4d
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util - Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket - jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka1_1  | [main] ERROR io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus - Timed out waiting for connection to Zookeeper server [zoo1:2181].
kafka1_1  | [main-SendThread(zoo1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zoo1/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka1_1  | [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x0 closed
kafka1_1  | [main-EventThread] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down for session: 0x0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: 1) Did Zookeeper actually start? 2) How about using the existing Docker compose files that Confluent provides? (And copy only Zookeeper and Kafka services from them)

Comment: I still get the same issue with confluent, unfortunately. That why I tried a different one. Using this one, https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-stack-docker-compose

Comment: I suggest following up on these issues https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-stack-docker-compose/issues/84 or https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-stack-docker-compose/issues/62 Otherwise, use this - https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/6.2.0-post/cp-all-in-one-community/docker-compose.yml#L2-L34

Answer (score 1):

Your zookeeper seems not to be running , please remove the following line and try again

```
ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
```

The above line is for communication to the zookeeper quorum and in your use case you set only one zookeeper and not 3/5

Please add logs from the docker of zookeeper startup if above answer does not resolve the issue

Comment: I did try that but didn't seem to work.  I've added the log to the question description.

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue, simplifying zookeeper config worked for me:

```
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181
    volumes:
      - kafka-storage:/data
      - kafka-storage:/datalog
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the missing environment ZOO_PORT string because of which I was getting "*ERROR Unable to open socket to zookeeper-kafka-learning-container:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO)*" error.

Final working docker compose yaml is:

```
version: '2'
services:

#Zookeeper Service.
zookeeper:
  image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
  restart: "no"
  ports:
    - '2181:2181'
  environment:
    - ZOO_PORT=2181
    - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  container_name: zookeeper-kafka-learning-container

#Kafka Service
kafka:
  image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
  restart: "no"
  ports:
    - '9092:9092'
    - '29092:29092'
  
environment:
  - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
  - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://:29092,EXTERNAL://:9092
  - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
  - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper-kafka-learning-container:2181
  - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
  - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
  
container_name: kafka-broker

depends_on:
  - "zookeeper"
```